# what is meant by the trans function in the code..and where is the quickadmin class located

Tags: php, laravel

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <strong>{{ trans('quickadmin::auth.whoops') }}</strong> {{ trans('quickadmin::auth.some_problems_with_input') }}
                        <br><br>
                        <ul>
                            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                            @endforeach
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                @endif
```

> I am new to laravel
>   What is the trans function in above code.?
>   And where is the quickadmin class located in laravel directories or it is pointing to main directory as name of the main directory is also quickadmin.

Answer (score 0):

`trans()` is a translation facade used by laravel to target the current language folder and map inside to reach the folder\file\key;

It is normally presented as a file that returns an array of `key => value` and should be located at `resources\lang\<current lang targeted>\file.php.key;`

The default targeted language is present at `config/app.php` under the key `locale` which, if it fails to detect it, you also can present the `fallback_locale` located just underneath the `locale` key under the same file.

To be honest I am not sure why is it created with `::` as a static method from a class. It is normally mapped as `folders and files`;

Each parent lang that you are supporting is denominated as a folder under `resources/lang` where the folder name is usually the `lang code`

Their [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/localization) is suberb and should be quick for you to wrap your head around it :)